# DB2 character conversion

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2 I have a column called `webIdentifier` in my table which is a 13 character field from the web that is getting saved with ccsid conversion.

So on the web I get back `'0213725502A33A32DAACAEB001'` but when  I query the database with it:

`select ID from testTable where webIdentifier = '0213725502A33A32DAACAEB001'`

I get no error but also no results.

How can I change this so I can query with ccsid 65535 on the character set above so that it actually finds the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think this will be what you want

```
select ID from testTable where webIdentifier = x'0213725502A33A32DAACAEB001'
```

Comment: Ok this does seem to work in the consolde but in a stored procedure I'm having an issue with ```where webIdentifier = x P_INPUT_ID```

Comment: I guess it depends on how you populate P_INPUT_ID.  Maybe ask a new question with an example stored procedure code, and note what version of Db2 you are using

Comment: the `x` (or `X` which also works) is used for binary-string constants. It is not an operator, just part of the literal syntax  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzbinconst.htm